# Solving general differential equation $h\left(f\left(x\right)\right)+g\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)=i\left(x\right)$ for $f\left(x\right)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I would like to solve the differential equation $h\left(f\left(x\right)\right)+g\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)=i\left(x\right)$ for $f\left(x\right)$.

I have the solution for the general differential equation $h\left(f\left(x\right)\right)+g\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)=K$ given functions $h$ and $g$, and constant $K$ assuming $g$ and $f$ are invertible.

Here it is:

$$\begin{align} & h\left(f\left(x\right)\right)+g\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)=K\tag{i}\\ & \implies g\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)=K-h\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\tag{ii}\\ & \implies f'\left(x\right)=g^{-1}\left(K-h\left(f\left(x\right)\right)\right)\tag{iii}\\ & \implies f'\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)=g^{-1}\left(K-h\left(x\right)\right)\tag{iv}\\ & \implies \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)=\dfrac{1}{g^{-1}\left(K-h\left(x\right)\right)}\tag{v}\\ & \implies f^{-1}\left(x\right)=\int \dfrac{1}{g^{-1}\left(K-h\left(x\right)\right)}dx\tag{vi}\\ & \implies f\left(x\right)=\left(\int \dfrac{1}{g^{-1}\left(K-h\left(x\right)\right)}dx\right)^{-1}\tag{vii}\end{align}$$

Comment: What happens between steps iv and v? Note that $\frac{d}{dx}f(f^{-1}(x))\neq \frac{d}{dx} f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: @probably_someone Between iv and v, both sides were reciprocated, making the left hand side $\frac{1}{f'\left(f^{-1}\left(x\right)\right)}$ which is $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}\left(x\right)$